# History of Reciprocity Laws

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

Does anybody know a freely available overview of the history of  Reciprocity Laws, especially the Cubic and Biquadratic ones? Wikipedia

I know about Franz Lemmermeyer's book "Reciprocity Laws", but sadly it is not available to me.

So far I have only found the following PDF about the history of the Quadratic Reciprocity Law:

http://seanelvidge.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/HistoryQR.pdf

Comment: Considering that F. Lemmermeyer's books are the definitive source, you might want to explore possible ways of obtaining a copy.

Comment: You can see parts of the book on [Googlebooks](https://books.google.com/books/about/Reciprocity_Laws.html?id=EwjpPeK6GpEC), Citeseer has a [free review](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=E8B1B197B7C34FFC4E6292AEC6E68D20?doi=10.1.1.192.1338&rep=rep1&type=pdf) of it. [Frei's The 
Reciprocity Law from Euler to Eisenstein](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~belked/lecturenotes/620E/Frei%20-%20The%20Reciprocity%20Law%20from%20Euler%20to%20Eisenstein.pdf) also covers the cubic law.